# Card size differentiate because of image height?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a design for users to select different templates. All functions work fine, but I have an issue with my card design because of the different image sizes.

I have tried all the ways using flex on row and column, fixed image size and card size but it has not worked.

Here is  my current screen:

[image]

```html
        <div class="row">
          <? $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM payslip_template WHERE status = 'a'");
          $i = 1;
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 imgcol">
              <div class="card imgcard" id="imgcard_<? echo $i; ?>" <? if($row[ 'temp_default']=='y' ) { ?>style="background-color:#8a7f83;"
                <? } else { ?> style="background-color:#dedad1;" <? } ?>>
                <div class="card-title text-center imgtitle">
                  <?= strtoupper($row['name']); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <img src="<?= $row['temp_image']; ?>" class="img-fluid">
                  <div class="row btnrow">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <button type="button" class="<?= $BUTTON_CLASS_DEFAULT; ?>" onclick="defaultact(this.value);" value="<?= $row['aid']." _ ".$i; ?>" style="width: 100%">
                      <i class="<?= $ICON_CLASS_DEFAULT; ?>"></i>
                      Default
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <button type="button" class="<?=$BUTTON_CLASS_PREVIEW; ?>" onclick='preview(this.value)' ; value="<?= $row['temp_image'];?>">
                      <i class="<?=$ICON_CLASS_PREVIEW; ?>"></i>
                      Preview
                    </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <? $i++; } ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your PHP isn't much use here...we need a [mcve]

Comment: @Paulie_D i have edited my question as possible

Comment: Paulie meant that the PHP markup is not relevant to the problem. We need to see the actual HTML output so we can recreate the issue in order to debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked fine by fixing all image are in same height and width.

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

> Using  `object-fit: contain;` along with some specific `height` (Which
>   suits your design) we will able set all size images in a container

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
img{  
      object-fit: contain;
      height: 60px;
      width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: red">
         <img width="100" height="100" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: yellow">
          <img width="100" height="100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: green">
         <img width="100" height="100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541233349642-6e425fe6190e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```